# Popup in new window opens in new tab instead

Tags: javascript, php

I have a calendar created with php.  In this calendar I have load_id's listed by date.  I made a popup to show more data for each load.  I want it to show as a popup not in a new tab.  I have tried doing it as a function but as I don't know javascript I could not figure out how to pass the load_id to the url.  If I replace "this.href" with the url in a function it works like a charm.  But again I don't know how to pass the load id as a variable so that won't work for me.  If someone could point out where I made my mistake passing the variable I would be much obliged!

This is what I have now:

```
echo "<span class='load_shipped'>
<a href='cal_popup.php?load_id=".$load_id."'
onclick='window.open(this.href, '_blank','left=100,top=100,width=500,height=500,toolbar=1,resizable=0');'>
".$load_id."
</a>
<br>
</span>\n";
```

I tried this as well to no avail:

```
echo "<span class='load_shipped'>
<a onclick='popup(".$load_id.");'>".$load_id."</a><br>
</span>\n";
```

Javascript:

```
<script>
    function popup(id){
        window.open('cal_popup.php?load_id=id', '_blank','left=100, top=100,width=500,height=500,toolbar=1,resizable=0');
    }
</script>
```

All this did though was pass 'id' instead of the real load_id.

Comment: `'cal_popup.php?load_id='+id`

Comment: Which Browser are you using?

Comment: @user790454 If I use 'cal_popup.php?load_id=+id' a popup opens but it passed "+id"  If I use 'cal_popup.php?load_id='+id nothing will happen when I click

Comment: @SSS I am using firefox.  I need it to be cross browser though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like you're having trouble because you're using the same quotes to wrap the attribute `onclick` and to define the parameters of the `window.open` call. Try using double quotes on the attribute. You'll also need to `return false;` at the end of the `onclick` to prevent the link working as normal.

```
echo "<span class='load_shipped'>
    <a href='cal_popup.php?load_id=".$load_id."'
    onclick=\"window.open(this.href, '_blank','left=100,top=100,width=500,height=500,toolbar=1,resizable=0');return false;\">
    ".$load_id."
    </a>
    <br>
</span>\n";
```

In your last example where you have the function `popup` - please note that you need to concatenate the `id` variable into the string like `'cal_popup.php?load_id=' + id`.

Comment: Thank you!  That is exactly what the problem was.  I needed escaped double quotes in the onclick event!  And the missing return false;